# moving WSL venv in Windows

Tags: windows, copy, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have started using WSL2 with windows 11.
Recently while organizing my folders I tried to copy and paste a few files created in WSL to a different location but I get the error "Error 0x80070780: The File Cannot Be Accessed by the System"

I have narrowed it to moving the python venv but I am still not getting how to move the files

Edit with additional details:
All my files are in the windows Directory only.
I am trying to copy the files from one folder to another
I am trying a simple copy and paste (ctrl-C ctrl-V)
Yes it only happens with the venv I made in WSL using

```
python3 -m venv ./venv
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: For question reviewers, this seems to me like a developer/programming focused question, since the OP says that it only happens with a `venv`.  Until and unless someone has a reason to believe this isn't the case, I'd recommend leaving it open here.

Comment: Can you provide some more details on what you are doing?  Are you moving the files from a Windows drive to WSL (or vice-versa)?  How are you moving them?  Explorer?  PowerShell?  Bash?  Please edit your question with any additional details.